# Dynamic routing of retrievers in LangChain

Tags: information-retrieval, langchain, large-language-model

In my use case a user selects a product and then enters a query. I need to run retrieval and generation to create a response. There are 3 different products, and for each one there is a different Elastic index.

A naive implementation would be to create 3 chains:

```
product A -> chain A = retriever A | prompt | llm
product B -> chain B = retriever B | prompt | llm
product C -> chain C = retriever C | prompt | llm
```

At inference time, I can select the right chain based on the product selection, and run the query through it.

However, I'm trying to explore a more advanced solution, where there is a single chain with dynamic routing between the retrievers:

```
chain D = retriever A/B/C | prompt | llm
```

My implementation looks like this:

```py
retrievers =  {
    "product_a": retriever_a,
    "product_b": retriever_b,
    "product_c": retriever_c
}

def retriever_router(info):
    return retrievers[info['product_id']]

chain = RunnableLambda(retriever_router) | prompt | llm

chain.invoke({"question": "Why is it so cold in Antartica",
              "product_id": "product_b"})
```

Although this code selects the right retriever, it subsequently runs the retriever with a dictionary of "question" and "product_id" as input. This is a problem because retrievers in LangChain expect to be invoked with the query string directly, not with a dictionary of parameters where the query is one of them.

Essentially, my problem is that with dynamic routing I need to pass the product id to pick the right retriever, but due to the fact that I'm also passing a question, it makes my input a dictionary, and the retriever expects a bare string input.

Does anyone have any idea how to deal with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a selector before the chain to decide which chain to use.
Seems it more easy to generate the dynamic chain.

Just like:

```
def selector(prompt_dict):
    return chain.map()

selector({"question": "Why is it so cold in Antartica",
              "product_id": "product_b"})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how this will solve the problem. How calling `map` would help?  and where do you use the `product_id` in `selector()`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround - instead of using a retriever directly, I use a wrapper to pass the question from the dictionary.

This is the wrapper code:

```py
class RetrieverWrapper(Runnable):
    def __init__(self, retriever):
        self.retriever = retriever

    def invoke(self, input: Input, config: Optional[RunnableConfig] = None) -> Output:
        return self.retriever.invoke(input=input['question'], config=config)

    async def ainvoke(self, input: Input, config: Optional[RunnableConfig] = None, **kwargs: Any) -> Output:
        return await self.retriever.ainvoke(input=input['question'], config=config, **kwargs)
```

And now `retriever_router` looks like this:

```py
def retriever_router(info):
    return RetrieverWrapper(retrievers[info['product_id']])
```